# Flask redirect (same route, different HTTP method) ends up in 302 loop

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to redirect from a `PUT` to a `GET` request and I end up on a 302 loop since the `request.method` seems to be set to `PUT` all the time. I have tried adding `_method='GET'` to the `url_for` function.

```py
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'PUT'])
def test_route():
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        ...
        return redirect(url_for('app.test_route'))
    else:
        return render_template('test.html')
```

The result then is:

```
[2020-02-24 04:44:06,093] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2020 04:44:06] "PUT /test HTTP/1.1" 302 -
[2020-02-24 04:44:06,207] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2020 04:44:06] "PUT /test HTTP/1.1" 302 -
[2020-02-24 04:44:06,331] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2020 04:44:06] "PUT /test HTTP/1.1" 302 -
[2020-02-24 04:44:06,468] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2020 04:44:06] "PUT /test HTTP/1.1" 302 -
[2020-02-24 04:44:06,567] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2020 04:44:06] "PUT /test HTTP/1.1" 302 -
[2020-02-24 04:44:06,687] INFO in _internal: 127.0.0.1 - - [24/Feb/2020 04:44:06] "PUT /test HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

I have looked it up in StackOverflow for similar issues but I have not found any working solution. It seems like an easy issue to solve but it has taken me more time than I would like to.

Comment: Which method to use is not defined for a 302. Try a 303 where it **should** be GET.

Comment: @KlausD. wow the 303 code actually worked. Could you elaborate on your answer more?

Answer (score 0):

I found a clear explanation at https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html.

> **303 See Other**
>
> The response to the request can be found under a different URI and
> SHOULD be retrieved using a GET method on that resource. This method
> exists primarily to allow the output of a POST-activated script to
> redirect the user agent to a selected resource. The new URI is not a
> substitute reference for the originally requested resource. The 303
> response MUST NOT be cached, but the response to the second
> (redirected) request might be cacheable.
>
> The different URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the
> response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the
> response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the
> new URI(s).

With that said, changing the default code of 302 did the trick:

```py
redirect(url_for('app.test_route'), code=303)
```